# Android Canvas Animation and basic Physics

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to create a UI similar to the one that Apple created for their Music app. I am specifically talking about rounded shaped items that you can scroll to explore different types of songs.

There is a video here that will help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gr2dn6IAVzU

Apple has a very strong graphic API that makes this UI really easy to code. For instance you can use physics, etc

I am very new with Android. Does Canvas allows me to do the same thing ? do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: my recommendation would be: please don't do that. This UI is annoying and a pain to use.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no UI tools like that, and definitely no built in physics engine like that on Android.  You can probably find libraries, but it will all be custom code.  And I wouldn't recommend Canvas for it, I'd go for OpenGL.

As an aside-  that is the ugliest, most annoying UI I've seen in my life.  I wouldn't use it if you paid me to.  UI elements shouldn't bounce around and move, it provides no benefit and makes the app harder to use.  Can you imagine using that if you had reduced vision, or motor control issues?  Whoever made that should be fired.  Its a great argument for making software be forced to comply to the ADA.

Comment: I am trying to come up with a new UI that will allow my users to explore and compare many items really fast. What UI would you recommend instead of the rounded balls ?

Comment: @Raha Did you have a chance to look at Foursquare? Foursquare has a somewhat similar/different way to choose options. It could be something that might interest you.

Comment: @Varun i did try to find it but couldn't find anything similar to Apple Music.